# Analysing crash dump

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, debugging, crash

On the customer unit, I see this crash and after the crash, the unit goes into hung state. Only hard reboot brings it back to the normal state. Below log shows many register values and memory locations. I am unable to locate the exact crash reason/module. There are no crash debug tools available on the unit. From the logs can we get some clue on the crash? Is it poe_isr module causing the issue? How to interpret these errors?

```
Modules linked in: nfnetlink fci(O) tempo(P) wan(P) common(P) ext2 jbd mbcache fmc_klm_helper(P) fmc_klm_timer(P) dspg_dect(O) auto_bridge(O) turnkey_decomp(P) decomp(O) cie(O) xt_dns nf_nat_tftp nf_conntrack_tftp nf_nat_snmp_basic nf_conntrack_snmp nf_nat_sip nf_conntrack_sip nf_nat_pptp nf_conntrack_pptp nf_nat_h323 nf_conntrack_h323 nf_nat_proto_gre nf_conntrack_proto_gre nf_nat_amanda nf_conntrack_amanda nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_irc nf_conntrack_irc nf_nat_ftp nf_conntrack_ftp xt_iprange xt_HL xt_hl ipt_ECN xt_CLASSIFY xt_time xt_tcpmss xt_statistic xt_mark xt_length xt_DSCP xt_dscp xt_string xt_layer7 xt_quota xt_pkttype xt_physdev xt_owner ipt_REDIRECT ipt_NETMAP ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_nat xt_recent xt_helper xt_connmark xt_connbytes xt_conntrack xt_CT xt_NOTRACK iptable_raw xt_state nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_conntrack ipt_REJECT xt_TCPMSS ipt_LOG xt_comment xt_multiport xt_mac xt_limit iptable_mangle iptable_filter ip_tables xt_tcpudp x_tables ppp_async pppoe pppox ppp_deflate ppp_generic slhc n_hdlc tamper_isr(O) poe_isr(O) adcmods(P) micphy(P) ftdi_sio cp210x pl2303 option usb_wwan usbserial usb_storage cdc_wdm cdc_acm nls_iso8859_15 nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 i2c_algo_pca i2c_algo_bit pfe(O) max310x regmap_spi zwave_spi(O) ts_fsm ts_bm ts_kmp crc_ccitt m86xxx_elp cryptosoft cryptodev(P) [last unloaded: fci]
CPU: 0    Tainted: P           O  (3.2.54 #2)
PC is at __rb_rotate_left+0x24/0x78
LR is at rb_insert_color+0x108/0x134
pc : [<c41aef04>]    lr : [<c41af0dc>]    psr: a0000013
sp : cf2c9ddc  ip : acc8089f  fp : cf2c9dec
r10: d0800000  r9 : d0800000  r8 : c8089fac
r7 : c96ae538  r6 : cf101ea8  r5 : cf101ea8  r4 : cf101ea8
r3 : cf101ea9  r2 : cf101ea8  r1 : c96ae538  r0 : cf101ea8
Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 10c53c7d  Table: 0f0fc04a  DAC: 00000015
Process insmod (pid: 31163, stack limit = 0xcf2c82f0)
Stack: (0xcf2c9ddc to 0xcf2ca000)
9dc0:                                                                cf101ea8
9de0: cf2c9e14 cf2c9df0 c41af0dc c41aeeec 00000000 c82384ec c82384e0 00000001
9e00: d668c000 00004000 cf2c9e2c cf2c9e18 c40d2120 c41aefe0 00000000 c82384e0
9e20: cf2c9e6c cf2c9e30 c40d30c0 c40d20b4 00003fff 00000000 ffffffff f0000000
9e40: c41af96c c7c4c940 00003000 00000022 00000001 000000d2 c406de40 d0800000
9e60: cf2c9ea4 cf2c9e70 c40d3268 c40d2eb0 000000d2 c8314800 cf2c9f78 000025ac
9e80: 000025ac 000000d2 c406de40 ffffffff cf2c8000 00000000 cf2c9ee4 cf2c9ea8
9ea0: c40d3bec c40d31a8 f0000000 000000d2 c406de40 00000001 ffffffff c8314800
9ec0: 00000000 000025ac 000025ac 00bf5198 00000080 c400de84 cf2c9f04 cf2c9ee8
9ee0: c40d3da0 c40d3b9c 000000d2 0000065f ffffffff c406de40 cf2c9f1c cf2c9f08
9f00: c40d3ee4 c40d3d6c ffffffff c406de40 cf2c9fa4 cf2c9f20 c406de40 c40d3ec0
9f20: c40e0be0 c40faf0c 00000020 00bf5188 c8314800 00000000 00000000 00000000
9f40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
9f60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c40dcd64 000025ac
9f80: 00000000 be8fff1b 00000080 c400de84 cf2c8000 00000000 00000000 cf2c9fa8
9fa0: c400dd00 c406ddf0 000025ac 00000000 00bf5198 000025ac 00bf5188 00bfd238
9fc0: 000025ac 00000000 be8fff1b 00000080 00000000 00000000 4003f000 00000000
9fe0: be8ffc78 be8ffc68 0001b73c 40242550 60000010 00bf5198 00000000 00000000
Backtrace: 
[<c41aeee0>] (__rb_rotate_left+0x0/0x78) from [<c41af0dc>] (rb_insert_color+0x108/0x134)
 r4:cf101ea8
[<c41aefd4>] (rb_insert_color+0x0/0x134) from [<c40d2120>] (__insert_vmap_area+0x78/0xd8)
 r8:00004000 r7:d668c000 r6:00000001 r5:c82384e0 r4:c82384ec
r3:00000000
[<c40d20a8>] (__insert_vmap_area+0x0/0xd8) from [<c40d30c0>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0x21c/0x2f8)
 r5:c82384e0 r4:00000000
[<c40d2ea4>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0x0/0x2f8) from [<c40d3268>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0xcc/0x164)
[<c40d319c>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0x0/0x164) from [<c40d3bec>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x5c/0x1d0)
[<c40d3b90>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x0/0x1d0) from [<c40d3da0>] (__vmalloc_node+0x40/0x4c)
 r8:c400de84 r7:00000080 r6:00bf5198 r5:000025ac r4:000025ac
[<c40d3d60>] (__vmalloc_node+0x0/0x4c) from [<c40d3ee4>] (vmalloc+0x30/0x3c)
[<c40d3eb4>] (vmalloc+0x0/0x3c) from [<c406de40>] (sys_init_module+0x5c/0x1878)
[<c406dde4>] (sys_init_module+0x0/0x1878) from [<c400dd00>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
Code: e593c008 e35c0000 e580c004 1593c008 (159c4000) 
---[ end trace ea9b8194d089d708 ]---
INFO: rcu_sched detected stall on CPU 0 (t=6000 jiffies)
Backtrace: 
[<c4011504>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x110) from [<c43924bc>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
 r6:c962e080 r5:c96462e0 r4:c9ec4674 r3:c96429bc
[<c43924a4>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c4082188>] (__rcu_pending+0x88/0x38c)
[<c4082100>] (__rcu_pending+0x0/0x38c) from [<c4083218>] (rcu_check_callbacks+0xe8/0x17c)
[<c4083130>] (rcu_check_callbacks+0x0/0x17c) from [<c4043ac4>] (update_process_times+0x40/0x64)
 r8:4d76447a r7:00000000 r6:c6f06ae0 r5:00000000 r4:c8ac8000
r3:00010000
[<c4043a84>] (update_process_times+0x0/0x64) from [<c406513c>] (tick_sched_timer+0x9c/0xdc)
 r7:c9ec44a0 r6:c8ac9dd8 r5:c8ac8000 r4:c9ec4598
[<c40650a0>] (tick_sched_timer+0x0/0xdc) from [<c405805c>] (__run_hrtimer+0xf4/0x1c8)
 r9:c8ac9d20 r8:4d763d80 r6:c9ec44d8 r5:c9ec44a0 r4:c9ec4598
[<c4057f68>] (__run_hrtimer+0x0/0x1c8) from [<c4058db4>] (hrtimer_interrupt+0x124/0x288)
[<c4058c90>] (hrtimer_interrupt+0x0/0x288) from [<c40139e0>] (twd_handler+0x28/0x30)
[<c40139b8>] (twd_handler+0x0/0x30) from [<c407f880>] (handle_percpu_devid_irq+0xd0/0x150)
 r4:0000001d r3:c40139b8
[<c407f7b0>] (handle_percpu_devid_irq+0x0/0x150) from [<c407be30>] (generic_handle_irq+0x34/0x48)
[<c407bdfc>] (generic_handle_irq+0x0/0x48) from [<c400e5e0>] (handle_IRQ+0x80/0xc0)
[<c400e560>] (handle_IRQ+0x0/0xc0) from [<c40081d0>] (asm_do_IRQ+0x10/0x14)
 r5:20000013 r4:c4395234
[<c40081c0>] (asm_do_IRQ+0x0/0x14) from [<c400d738>] (__irq_svc+0x38/0x120)
Exception stack(0xc8ac9dd8 to 0xc8ac9e20)
9dc0:                                                       c96ae534 00000013
9de0: 00000001 00000001 c96ae52c c82385a0 00000001 00000001 00006000 d0800000
9e00: d0800000 c8ac9e2c c8ac9e30 c8ac9e20 c40d2f4c c4395234 20000013 ffffffff
[<c4395218>] (_raw_spin_lock+0x0/0x30) from [<c40d2f4c>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0xa8/0x2f8)
[<c40d2ea4>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0x0/0x2f8) from [<c40d3268>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0xcc/0x164)
[<c40d319c>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0x0/0x164) from [<c40d3bec>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x5c/0x1d0)
[<c40d3b90>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x0/0x1d0) from [<c40d3da0>] (__vmalloc_node+0x40/0x4c)
 r8:c400de84 r7:00000080 r6:00b7a080 r5:0000465c r4:0000465c
[<c40d3d60>] (__vmalloc_node+0x0/0x4c) from [<c40d3ee4>] (vmalloc+0x30/0x3c)
[<c40d3eb4>] (vmalloc+0x0/0x3c) from [<c406de40>] (sys_init_module+0x5c/0x1878)
[<c406dde4>] (sys_init_module+0x0/0x1878) from [<c400dd00>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
INFO: rcu_sched detected stall on CPU 0 (t=60090 jiffies)
Backtrace: 
[<c4011504>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x110) from [<c43924bc>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
 r6:c962e080 r5:c96462e0 r4:c9ec4674 r3:c96429bc
[<c43924a4>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c4082188>] (__rcu_pending+0x88/0x38c)
[<c4082100>] (__rcu_pending+0x0/0x38c) from [<c4083218>] (rcu_check_callbacks+0xe8/0x17c)
[<c4083130>] (rcu_check_callbacks+0x0/0x17c) from [<c4043ac4>] (update_process_times+0x40/0x64)
 r8:482def2a r7:00000000 r6:c6f06ae0 r5:00000000 r4:c8ac8000
r3:00010000
[<c4043a84>] (update_process_times+0x0/0x64) from [<c406513c>] (tick_sched_timer+0x9c/0xdc)
 r7:c9ec44a0 r6:c8ac9dd8 r5:c8ac8000 r4:c9ec4598
[<c40650a0>] (tick_sched_timer+0x0/0xdc) from [<c405805c>] (__run_hrtimer+0xf4/0x1c8)
 r9:c8ac9d20 r8:482de880 r6:c9ec44d8 r5:c9ec44a0 r4:c9ec4598
[<c4057f68>] (__run_hrtimer+0x0/0x1c8) from [<c4058db4>] (hrtimer_interrupt+0x124/0x288)
[<c4058c90>] (hrtimer_interrupt+0x0/0x288) from [<c40139e0>] (twd_handler+0x28/0x30)
[<c40139b8>] (twd_handler+0x0/0x30) from [<c407f880>] (handle_percpu_devid_irq+0xd0/0x150)
 r4:0000001d r3:c40139b8
[<c407f7b0>] (handle_percpu_devid_irq+0x0/0x150) from [<c407be30>] (generic_handle_irq+0x34/0x48)
[<c407bdfc>] (generic_handle_irq+0x0/0x48) from [<c400e5e0>] (handle_IRQ+0x80/0xc0)
[<c400e560>] (handle_IRQ+0x0/0xc0) from [<c40081d0>] (asm_do_IRQ+0x10/0x14)
 r5:20000013 r4:c4395234
[<c40081c0>] (asm_do_IRQ+0x0/0x14) from [<c400d738>] (__irq_svc+0x38/0x120)
Exception stack(0xc8ac9dd8 to 0xc8ac9e20)
9dc0:                                                       c96ae534 00000013
9de0: 00000001 00000001 c96ae52c c82385a0 00000001 00000001 00006000 d0800000
9e00: d0800000 c8ac9e2c c8ac9e30 c8ac9e20 c40d2f4c c4395234 20000013 ffffffff
[<c4395218>] (_raw_spin_lock+0x0/0x30) from [<c40d2f4c>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0xa8/0x2f8)
[<c40d2ea4>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0x0/0x2f8) from [<c40d3268>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0xcc/0x164)
[<c40d319c>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0x0/0x164) from [<c40d3bec>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x5c/0x1d0)
[<c40d3b90>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x0/0x1d0) from [<c40d3da0>] (__vmalloc_node+0x40/0x4c)
 r8:c400de84 r7:00000080 r6:00b7a080 r5:0000465c r4:0000465c
[<c40d3d60>] (__vmalloc_node+0x0/0x4c) from [<c40d3ee4>] (vmalloc+0x30/0x3c)
[<c40d3eb4>] (vmalloc+0x0/0x3c) from [<c406de40>] (sys_init_module+0x5c/0x1878)
[<c406dde4>] (sys_init_module+0x0/0x1878) from [<c400dd00>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
INFO: rcu_sched detected stall on CPU 0 (t=78120 jiffies)
Backtrace: 
[<c4011504>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x110) from [<c43924bc>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
 r6:c962e080 r5:c96462e0 r4:c9ec4674 r3:c96429bc
[<c43924a4>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c4082188>] (__rcu_pending+0x88/0x38c)
[<c4082100>] (__rcu_pending+0x0/0x38c) from [<c4083218>] (rcu_check_callbacks+0xe8/0x17c)
[<c4083130>] (rcu_check_callbacks+0x0/0x17c) from [<c4043ac4>] (update_process_times+0x40/0x64)
 r8:42e59a72 r7:00000000 r6:c6f06ae0 r5:00000000 r4:c8ac8000
r3:00010000
[<c4043a84>] (update_process_times+0x0/0x64) from [<c406513c>] (tick_sched_timer+0x9c/0xdc)
 r7:c9ec44a0 r6:c8ac9dd8 r5:c8ac8000 r4:c9ec4598
[<c40650a0>] (tick_sched_timer+0x0/0xdc) from [<c405805c>] (__run_hrtimer+0xf4/0x1c8)
 r9:c8ac9d20 r8:42e59380 r6:c9ec44d8 r5:c9ec44a0 r4:c9ec4598
[<c4057f68>] (__run_hrtimer+0x0/0x1c8) from [<c4058db4>] (hrtimer_interrupt+0x124/0x288)
[<c4058c90>] (hrtimer_interrupt+0x0/0x288) from [<c40139e0>] (twd_handler+0x28/0x30)
[<c40139b8>] (twd_handler+0x0/0x30) from [<c407f880>] (handle_percpu_devid_irq+0xd0/0x150)
 r4:0000001d r3:c40139b8
[<c407f7b0>] (handle_percpu_devid_irq+0x0/0x150) from [<c407be30>] (generic_handle_irq+0x34/0x48)
[<c407bdfc>] (generic_handle_irq+0x0/0x48) from [<c400e5e0>] (handle_IRQ+0x80/0xc0)
[<c400e560>] (handle_IRQ+0x0/0xc0) from [<c40081d0>] (asm_do_IRQ+0x10/0x14)
 r5:20000013 r4:c4395234
[<c40081c0>] (asm_do_IRQ+0x0/0x14) from [<c400d738>] (__irq_svc+0x38/0x120)
Exception stack(0xc8ac9dd8 to 0xc8ac9e20)
9dc0:                                                       c96ae534 00000013
9de0: 00000001 00000001 c96ae52c c82385a0 00000001 00000001 00006000 d0800000
9e00: d0800000 c8ac9e2c c8ac9e30 c8ac9e20 c40d2f4c c4395234 20000013 ffffffff
[<c4395218>] (_raw_spin_lock+0x0/0x30) from [<c40d2f4c>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0xa8/0x2f8)
[<c40d2ea4>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0x0/0x2f8) from [<c40d3268>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0xcc/0x164)
[<c40d319c>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0x0/0x164) from [<c40d3bec>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x5c/0x1d0)
[<c40d3b90>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x0/0x1d0) from [<c40d3da0>] (__vmalloc_node+0x40/0x4c)
 r8:c400de84 r7:00000080 r6:00b7a080 r5:0000465c r4:0000465c
[<c40d3d60>] (__vmalloc_node+0x0/0x4c) from [<c40d3ee4>] (vmalloc+0x30/0x3c)
[<c40d3eb4>] (vmalloc+0x0/0x3c) from [<c406de40>] (sys_init_module+0x5c/0x1878)
[<c406dde4>] (sys_init_module+0x0/0x1878) from [<c400dd00>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
INFO: rcu_sched detected stall on CPU 0 (t=96150 jiffies)
Backtrace: 
[<c4011504>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x110) from [<c43924bc>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
 r6:c962e080 r5:c96462e0 r4:c9ec4674 r3:c96429bc
[<c43924a4>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c4082188>] (__rcu_pending+0x88/0x38c)
[<c4082100>] (__rcu_pending+0x0/0x38c) from [<c4083218>] (rcu_check_callbacks+0xe8/0x17c)
[<c4083130>] (rcu_check_callbacks+0x0/0x17c) from [<c4043ac4>] (update_process_times+0x40/0x64)
 r8:2dc446a2 r7:00000000 r6:c6f06ae0 r5:00000000 r4:c8ac8000
r3:00010000
[<c4043a84>] (update_process_times+0x0/0x64) from [<c406513c>] (tick_sched_timer+0x9c/0xdc)
 r7:c9ec44a0 r6:c8ac9dd8 r5:c8ac8000 r4:c9ec4598
[<c40650a0>] (tick_sched_timer+0x0/0xdc) from [<c405805c>] (__run_hrtimer+0xf4/0x1c8)
 r9:c8ac9d20 r8:2dc43f80 r6:c9ec44d8 r5:c9ec44a0 r4:c9ec4598
[<c4057f68>] (__run_hrtimer+0x0/0x1c8) from [<c4058db4>] (hrtimer_interrupt+0x124/0x288)
[<c4058c90>] (hrtimer_interrupt+0x0/0x288) from [<c40139e0>] (twd_handler+0x28/0x30)
[<c40139b8>] (twd_handler+0x0/0x30) from [<c407f880>] (handle_percpu_devid_irq+0xd0/0x150)
 r4:0000001d r3:c40139b8
[<c407f7b0>] (handle_percpu_devid_irq+0x0/0x150) from [<c407be30>] (generic_handle_irq+0x34/0x48)
[<c407bdfc>] (generic_handle_irq+0x0/0x48) from [<c400e5e0>] (handle_IRQ+0x80/0xc0)
[<c400e560>] (handle_IRQ+0x0/0xc0) from [<c40081d0>] (asm_do_IRQ+0x10/0x14)
 r5:20000013 r4:c4395234
[<c40081c0>] (asm_do_IRQ+0x0/0x14) from [<c400d738>] (__irq_svc+0x38/0x120)
Exception stack(0xc8ac9dd8 to 0xc8ac9e20)
9dc0:                                                       c96ae534 00000013
9de0: 00000001 00000001 c96ae52c c82385a0 00000001 00000001 00006000 d0800000
9e00: d0800000 c8ac9e2c c8ac9e30 c8ac9e20 c40d2f4c c4395234 20000013 ffffffff
[<c4395218>] (_raw_spin_lock+0x0/0x30) from [<c40d2f4c>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0xa8/0x2f8)
[<c40d2ea4>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0x0/0x2f8) from [<c40d3268>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0xcc/0x164)
[<c40d319c>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0x0/0x164) from [<c40d3bec>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x5c/0x1d0)
[<c40d3b90>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x0/0x1d0) from [<c40d3da0>] (__vmalloc_node+0x40/0x4c)
 r8:c400de84 r7:00000080 r6:00b7a080 r5:0000465c r4:0000465c
[<c40d3d60>] (__vmalloc_node+0x0/0x4c) from [<c40d3ee4>] (vmalloc+0x30/0x3c)
[<c40d3eb4>] (vmalloc+0x0/0x3c) from [<c406de40>] (sys_init_module+0x5c/0x1878)
[<c406dde4>] (sys_init_module+0x0/0x1878) from [<c400dd00>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
INFO: rcu_sched detected stall on CPU 0 (t=168270 jiffies)
Backtrace: 
[<c4011504>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x110) from [<c43924bc>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
 r6:c962e080 r5:c96462e0 r4:c9ec4674 r3:c96429bc
[<c43924a4>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c4082188>] (__rcu_pending+0x88/0x38c)
[<c4082100>] (__rcu_pending+0x0/0x38c) from [<c4083218>] (rcu_check_callbacks+0xe8/0x17c)
[<c4083130>] (rcu_check_callbacks+0x0/0x17c) from [<c4043ac4>] (update_process_times+0x40/0x64)
 r8:287bf122 r7:00000000 r6:c6f06ae0 r5:00000000 r4:c8ac8000
r3:00010000
[<c4043a84>] (update_process_times+0x0/0x64) from [<c406513c>] (tick_sched_timer+0x9c/0xdc)
 r7:c9ec44a0 r6:c8ac9dd8 r5:c8ac8000 r4:c9ec4598
[<c40650a0>] (tick_sched_timer+0x0/0xdc) from [<c405805c>] (__run_hrtimer+0xf4/0x1c8)
 r9:c8ac9d20 r8:287bea80 r6:c9ec44d8 r5:c9ec44a0 r4:c9ec4598
[<c4057f68>] (__run_hrtimer+0x0/0x1c8) from [<c4058db4>] (hrtimer_interrupt+0x124/0x288)
[<c4058c90>] (hrtimer_interrupt+0x0/0x288) from [<c40139e0>] (twd_handler+0x28/0x30)
[<c40139b8>] (twd_handler+0x0/0x30) from [<c407f880>] (handle_percpu_devid_irq+0xd0/0x150)
 r4:0000001d r3:c40139b8
[<c407f7b0>] (handle_percpu_devid_irq+0x0/0x150) from [<c407be30>] (generic_handle_irq+0x34/0x48)
[<c407bdfc>] (generic_handle_irq+0x0/0x48) from [<c400e5e0>] (handle_IRQ+0x80/0xc0)
[<c400e560>] (handle_IRQ+0x0/0xc0) from [<c40081d0>] (asm_do_IRQ+0x10/0x14)
 r5:20000013 r4:c4395234
[<c40081c0>] (asm_do_IRQ+0x0/0x14) from [<c400d738>] (__irq_svc+0x38/0x120)
Exception stack(0xc8ac9dd8 to 0xc8ac9e20)
9dc0:                                                       c96ae534 00000013
9de0: 00000001 00000001 c96ae52c c82385a0 00000001 00000001 00006000 d0800000
9e00: d0800000 c8ac9e2c c8ac9e30 c8ac9e20 c40d2f4c c4395234 20000013 ffffffff
[<c4395218>] (_raw_spin_lock+0x0/0x30) from [<c40d2f4c>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0xa8/0x2f8)
[<c40d2ea4>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0x0/0x2f8) from [<c40d3268>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0xcc/0x164)
[<c40d319c>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0x0/0x164) from [<c40d3bec>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x5c/0x1d0)
[<c40d3b90>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x0/0x1d0) from [<c40d3da0>] (__vmalloc_node+0x40/0x4c)
 r8:c400de84 r7:00000080 r6:00b7a080 r5:0000465c r4:0000465c
[<c40d3d60>] (__vmalloc_node+0x0/0x4c) from [<c40d3ee4>] (vmalloc+0x30/0x3c)
[<c40d3eb4>] (vmalloc+0x0/0x3c) from [<c406de40>] (sys_init_module+0x5c/0x1878)
[<c406dde4>] (sys_init_module+0x0/0x1878) from [<c400dd00>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
acpower_isr() [105]
poe_isr() [136]
INFO: rcu_sched detected stall on CPU 0 (t=186300 jiffies)
```

Answer (score 1):

[This document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/stallwarn.txt) describes RCU's CPU Stall errors. I saw this kind of hanging happening when interrupt handler was triggered, but interrupt flag is not reset, i.e. interrupt handler keeps executing indefinitely. Does this happen when you insert a module?

Comment: Not sure whether this is happening during a module insertion.